# Android - How to display Image uploading progress in Notification Bar?

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

I am trying to show uploading progress in Notification Bar but When I tried it Notification goes like `Upload in Progress - Upload Finished` and It keeps getting repeated. So, Here is the code that I have tried.

**My Notification Code**

```
private void uploadMediaNotification(int progress) {

NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, OfflineCapabilities.CHANNEL_2_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_cloud_upload_24)
        .setContentTitle("Uploading Media")
        .setContentText("Uploading in Progress")
        .setProgress(100, 0, false)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);

compat.notify(2, notification.build());

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        for (int progres = 0; progres < progress; progres += progress) {
            notification.setProgress(100, progres, false);
            compat.notify(2, notification.build());
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }
        notification.setContentText("Uploading Finished")
                .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                .setOngoing(false);
        compat.notify(2, notification.build());
    }
}).start();
}
```

**And Code for Upload Task**

```
final UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(imageURI);
    uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            uploadMediaNotification((int) progress);
        }
    });
```

Any Help or Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues. One is that the function uploadMediaNotification always **creates a new notification using the notification.builder when it is called**. To mitigate this, put the initialisation and update in two different functions, such as createUploadMediaNotification() and updateUploadMediaNotification()

Secondly, your Thread is quite useless, as you already get the percent progress passed to the function. This means the only thing you need to do is either set the progress and if it's 100% (i.e. completed) change the text to say that it is finished.

Here's a quick example:

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder notification;

private void createUploadMediaNotification() {
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, OfflineCapabilities.CHANNEL_2_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_cloud_upload_24)
        .setContentTitle("Uploading Media")
        .setContentText("Uploading in Progress")
        .setProgress(100, 0, false)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);

    compat.notify(2, notification.build());
}

private void updateUploadMediaNotification(int progress) {

    if(progress != 100) { //Progress is lower than 100%, updating progress
        notification.setProgress(100, progress, false);
    } else { //progress is 100%, changing notification content
        notification.setContentText("Uploading Finished")
                .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                .setOngoing(false);
    }

    //Update the notification
    compat.notify(2, notification.build());
}
```

For more info, check [this example on Android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#progressbar). Hope it helped. (Please forgive me if there are errors in the code, I just wrote this in a browser)

Comment: It works but it doesn't show progress it just shows uploading in progress and when uploading is done then it shows uploading finished. So, how can i show progress

Comment: I just edited the code, can you see if it works now? (I changed setProgress to notification.setProgress)